# Error de testeo con Node, Supertest y Jest

Tags: nodejs, express, jest

No logro solucionar un error que me da al testear un backend de Node (express) con Supertest:

```
const supertest = require('supertest')
const mongoose = require('mongoose')

const app = require('../app')

const api = supertest(app)

test('notes are returned as json', async () => {
  await api
    .get('/api/notes')
    .expect(200)
    .expect('Content-Type', /application\/json/)
}, 100000)

test('there are two notes', async () => {
  const response = await api.get('/api/notes')

  expect(response.body).toHaveLength(2)
})

test('the first note is about HTTP methods', async () => {
  const response = await api.get('/api/notes')

  expect(response.body[0].content).toBe('HTML is easy')
})

afterAll(() => {
  mongoose.connection.close()
})
```

Aclaración: El archivo app es donde está toda la lógica de Express.
El primer test parece que no hay problema.
El segundo test me indica que se recibe 0 datos. Cosa que no es correcta. Se deberían recibir datos, por lo que me da que response.body no trabaja bien.
En el tercer test da un error claro:
**TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'content')**
Entiendo que el problema es que no trabaja el body al igual que el anterior, ya que no puede leer la propiedad.

Gracias

Un saludo